# Different performance of "if" and "if else" in Java

Tags: java, performance, jvm, jmh

I noticed that `if else` / ternary (`condition ? a : b`) assigment  is faster than conditional assigment in `if` only statement. I performed JMH benchmarks on different JDKs but i will focus on JDK 12.

**(ops / sec, higher is better)**
[image: JMH benchmark]

**Source code:**

```
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
public class FindMaxBenchmark {
    public static int SIZE = 1_000_000;

    @Benchmark
    @CompilerControl(CompilerControl.Mode.DONT_INLINE)
    public static void findMax_if(Blackhole bh, Mock mock) {
        int result = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int[] data = mock.tab;

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i] > result) {
                result = data[i];
            }
        }

        bh.consume(result);
    }

    @Benchmark
    @CompilerControl(CompilerControl.Mode.DONT_INLINE)
    public static void findMax_if_else(Blackhole bh, Mock mock) {
        int result = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int[] data = mock.tab;

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i] > result) {
                result = data[i];
            } else {
                result = result;
            }
        }

        bh.consume(result);
    }

    @Benchmark
    @CompilerControl(CompilerControl.Mode.DONT_INLINE)
    public static void findMax_ternary(Blackhole bh, Mock mock) {
        int result = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int[] data = mock.tab;

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            result = data[i] > result ? data[i] : result;
        }

        bh.consume(result);
    }

    @Benchmark
    @CompilerControl(CompilerControl.Mode.DONT_INLINE)
    public static void findMax_intrinsicMax(Blackhole bh, Mock mock) {
        int result = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int[] data = mock.tab;

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            result = Math.max(data[i], result);
        }

        bh.consume(result);
    }

    @State(Scope.Thread)
    public static class Mock {
        private int[] tab = new int[SIZE];

        public int[] getTab() {
            return tab;
        }

        @Setup(Level.Iteration)
        public void setup() {
            Random r = new Random();
            this.tab = r.ints(SIZE).toArray();
        }
    }
}
```

**`findMax_if_else` perfasm output (ternary is almost the same):**

```
c2, level 4, codes.dbg.FindMaxBenchmark::findMax_if_else, version 493 (165 bytes)

                             0x00007fc7a8671a6b: cmp    r8d,ebp
         ╭                   0x00007fc7a8671a6e: jae    0x00007fc7a8671b3d
         │                   0x00007fc7a8671a74: mov    edx,DWORD PTR [r9+0x10]        ;*iaload {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         │                                                                             ; - codes.dbg.FindMaxBenchmark::findMax_if_else@21 (line 34)
         │                   0x00007fc7a8671a78: cmp    edx,0x80000000
         │╭                  0x00007fc7a8671a7e: jg     0x00007fc7a8671a85             ;*if_icmple {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         ││                                                                            ; - codes.dbg.FindMaxBenchmark::findMax_if_else@23 (line 34)
         ││                  0x00007fc7a8671a80: mov    edx,0x80000000                 ;*iinc {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         ││                                                                            ; - codes.dbg.FindMaxBenchmark::findMax_if_else@36 (line 33)
         │↘                  0x00007fc7a8671a85: mov    ebx,ebp
  0.02%  │                   0x00007fc7a8671a87: add    ebx,0xfffffffd
         │                   0x00007fc7a8671a8a: cmp    r8d,ebx
         │                   0x00007fc7a8671a8d: cmovl  ebx,r11d
         │                   0x00007fc7a8671a91: mov    r8d,0x1
  0.00%  │                   0x00007fc7a8671a97: cmp    ebx,0x1
         │ ╭                 0x00007fc7a8671a9a: jle    0x00007fc7a8671b00
         │ │                 0x00007fc7a8671a9c: mov    rdi,r9                         ;*goto {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         │ │                                                                           ; - codes.dbg.FindMaxBenchmark::findMax_if_else@39 (line 33)
         │ │╭                0x00007fc7a8671a9f: jmp    0x00007fc7a8671ab9
  0.01%  │ ││     ↗          0x00007fc7a8671aa1: mov    edx,ecx
         │ ││     │          0x00007fc7a8671aa3: nop    DWORD PTR [rax+0x0]
         │ ││     │          0x00007fc7a8671aaa: nop    WORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]
  8.06%  │ ││    ↗│          0x00007fc7a8671ab0: add    r8d,0x4                        ;*iinc {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         │ ││    ││                                                                    ; - codes.dbg.FindMaxBenchmark::findMax_if_else@36 (line 33)
 11.38%  │ ││    ││          0x00007fc7a8671ab4: cmp    r8d,ebx
 13.63%  │ ││╭   ││          0x00007fc7a8671ab7: jge    0x00007fc7a8671af1             ;*aload_3 {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         │ │││   ││                                                                    ; - codes.dbg.FindMaxBenchmark::findMax_if_else@18 (line 34)
  3.02%  │ │↘│   ││   ↗      0x00007fc7a8671ab9: mov    r11d,DWORD PTR [r9+r8*4+0x10]  ;*iaload {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         │ │ │   ││   │                                                                ; - codes.dbg.FindMaxBenchmark::findMax_if_else@21 (line 34)
  8.53%  │ │ │   ││   │      0x00007fc7a8671abe: cmp    r11d,edx
  4.54%  │ │ │╭  ││   │      0x00007fc7a8671ac1: jg     0x00007fc7a8671ae2             ;*iinc {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         │ │ ││  ││   │                                                                ; - codes.dbg.FindMaxBenchmark::findMax_if_else@36 (line 33)
  4.96%  │ │ ││  ││↗  │      0x00007fc7a8671ac3: mov    r11d,DWORD PTR [r9+r8*4+0x14]  ;*iaload {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         │ │ ││  │││  │                                                                ; - codes.dbg.FindMaxBenchmark::findMax_if_else@21 (line 34)
  3.73%  │ │ ││  │││  │      0x00007fc7a8671ac8: cmp    r11d,edx
  9.19%  │ │ ││╭ │││  │      0x00007fc7a8671acb: jg     0x00007fc7a8671ae7             ;*iinc {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         │ │ │││ │││  │                                                                ; - codes.dbg.FindMaxBenchmark::findMax_if_else@36 (line 33)
  3.70%  │ │ │││ │││↗ │      0x00007fc7a8671acd: mov    r11d,DWORD PTR [r9+r8*4+0x18]  ;*iaload {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         │ │ │││ ││││ │                                                                ; - codes.dbg.FindMaxBenchmark::findMax_if_else@21 (line 34)
  4.96%  │ │ │││ ││││ │      0x00007fc7a8671ad2: cmp    r11d,edx
  4.45%  │ │ │││╭││││ │      0x00007fc7a8671ad5: jg     0x00007fc7a8671aec             ;*iinc {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         │ │ ││││││││ │                                                                ; - codes.dbg.FindMaxBenchmark::findMax_if_else@36 (line 33)
  8.55%  │ │ ││││││││↗│      0x00007fc7a8671ad7: mov    ecx,DWORD PTR [r9+r8*4+0x1c]   ;*iaload {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         │ │ ││││││││││                                                                ; - codes.dbg.FindMaxBenchmark::findMax_if_else@21 (line 34)
  6.11%  │ │ ││││││││││      0x00007fc7a8671adc: cmp    ecx,edx
  2.48%  │ │ ││││╰│││││      0x00007fc7a8671ade: jle    0x00007fc7a8671ab0             ;*if_icmple {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         │ │ ││││ │││││                                                                ; - codes.dbg.FindMaxBenchmark::findMax_if_else@23 (line 34)
         │ │ ││││ ╰││││      0x00007fc7a8671ae0: jmp    0x00007fc7a8671aa1
         │ │ │↘││  ││││      0x00007fc7a8671ae2: mov    edx,r11d
  0.00%  │ │ │ ││  ╰│││      0x00007fc7a8671ae5: jmp    0x00007fc7a8671ac3
  0.00%  │ │ │ ↘│   │││      0x00007fc7a8671ae7: mov    edx,r11d
  0.00%  │ │ │  │   ╰││      0x00007fc7a8671aea: jmp    0x00007fc7a8671acd
  0.00%  │ │ │  ↘    ││      0x00007fc7a8671aec: mov    edx,r11d
  0.00%  │ │ │       ╰│      0x00007fc7a8671aef: jmp    0x00007fc7a8671ad7
         │ │ ↘        │      0x00007fc7a8671af1: mov    r11,QWORD PTR [r15+0x108]      ; ImmutableOopMap{r10=Oop r9=NarrowOop rdi=Oop }
         │ │          │                                                                ;*goto {reexecute=1 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         │ │          │                                                                ; - codes.dbg.FindMaxBenchmark::findMax_if_else@39 (line 33)
         │ │          │      0x00007fc7a8671af8: test   DWORD PTR [r11],eax            ;*goto {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         │ │          │                                                                ; - codes.dbg.FindMaxBenchmark::findMax_if_else@39 (line 33)
         │ │          │                                                                ;   {poll}
         │ │          │      0x00007fc7a8671afb: cmp    r8d,ebx
  0.00%  │ │          ╰      0x00007fc7a8671afe: jl     0x00007fc7a8671ab9
         │ ↘                 0x00007fc7a8671b00: cmp    r8d,ebp
  0.00%  │             ╭     0x00007fc7a8671b03: jge    0x00007fc7a8671b1a
         │             │     0x00007fc7a8671b05: data16 xchg ax,ax                     ;*aload_3 {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         │             │                                                               ; - codes.dbg.FindMaxBenchmark::findMax_if_else@18 (line 34)
         │             │ ↗   0x00007fc7a8671b08: mov    r11d,DWORD PTR [r9+r8*4+0x10]  ;*iaload {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         │             │ │                                                             ; - codes.dbg.FindMaxBenchmark::findMax_if_else@21 (line 34)
  0.01%  │             │ │   0x00007fc7a8671b0d: cmp    r11d,edx
         │             │╭│   0x00007fc7a8671b10: jg     0x00007fc7a8671b38
         │             │││↗  0x00007fc7a8671b12: inc    r8d                            ;*iinc {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         │             ││││                                                            ; - codes.dbg.FindMaxBenchmark::findMax_if_else@36 (line 33)
         │             ││││  0x00007fc7a8671b15: cmp    r8d,ebp
         │             ││╰│  0x00007fc7a8671b18: jl     0x00007fc7a8671b08             ;*if_icmpge {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         │             ││ │                                                            ; - codes.dbg.FindMaxBenchmark::findMax_if_else@15 (line 33)
         │             ↘│ │  0x00007fc7a8671b1a: test   r10,r10
  0.00%  │              │ │  0x00007fc7a8671b1d: je     0x00007fc7a8671b52
         │              │ │  0x00007fc7a8671b1f: mov    rsi,r10
         │              │ │  0x00007fc7a8671b22: nop
         │              │ │  0x00007fc7a8671b23: call   0x00007fc7a8671ba0             ; ImmutableOopMap{}
         │              │ │                                                            ;*invokevirtual consume {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         │              │ │                                                            ; - codes.dbg.FindMaxBenchmark::findMax_if_else@44 (line 41)
         │              │ │                                                            ;   {optimized virtual_call}
         │              │ │  0x00007fc7a8671b28: add    rsp,0x20
  0.01%  │              │ │  0x00007fc7a8671b2c: pop    rbp
         │              │ │  0x00007fc7a8671b2d: mov    r10,QWORD PTR [r15+0x108]
         │              │ │  0x00007fc7a8671b34: test   DWORD PTR [r10],eax            ;   {poll_return}
         │              │ │  0x00007fc7a8671b37: ret
         │              ↘ │  0x00007fc7a8671b38: mov    edx,r11d
         │                ╰  0x00007fc7a8671b3b: jmp    0x00007fc7a8671b12
         ↘                   0x00007fc7a8671b3d: mov    esi,0xffffff7e
                             0x00007fc7a8671b42: mov    QWORD PTR [rsp],r10
                             0x00007fc7a8671b46: mov    DWORD PTR [rsp+0x8],r9d
                             0x00007fc7a8671b4b: call   0x00007fc7a0ba3d00             ; ImmutableOopMap{[0]=Oop [8]=NarrowOop }
                                                                                       ;*if_icmpge {reexecute=1 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
```

**`findMax_if` perfasm output:**

```
c2, level 4, codes.dbg.FindMaxBenchmark::findMax_if, version 480 (165 bytes)

                              0x00007f34cc66e7eb: cmp    r8d,ebp
         ╭                    0x00007f34cc66e7ee: jae    0x00007f34cc66e8c4
         │                    0x00007f34cc66e7f4: mov    edx,DWORD PTR [r9+0x10]        ;*iaload {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         │                                                                              ; - codes.dbg.FindMaxBenchmark::findMax_if@21 (line 19)
         │                    0x00007f34cc66e7f8: cmp    edx,0x80000000
         │╭                   0x00007f34cc66e7fe: jg     0x00007f34cc66e805             ;*if_icmple {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         ││                                                                             ; - codes.dbg.FindMaxBenchmark::findMax_if@23 (line 19)
         ││                   0x00007f34cc66e800: mov    edx,0x80000000                 ;*iinc {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         ││                                                                             ; - codes.dbg.FindMaxBenchmark::findMax_if@31 (line 18)
         │↘                   0x00007f34cc66e805: mov    ebx,ebp
  0.01%  │                    0x00007f34cc66e807: add    ebx,0xfffffffd
         │                    0x00007f34cc66e80a: cmp    r8d,ebx
         │                    0x00007f34cc66e80d: cmovl  ebx,r11d
         │                    0x00007f34cc66e811: mov    r8d,0x1
         │                    0x00007f34cc66e817: cmp    ebx,0x1
         │ ╭                  0x00007f34cc66e81a: jle    0x00007f34cc66e880
         │ │                  0x00007f34cc66e81c: mov    rdi,r9                         ;*goto {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         │ │                                                                            ; - codes.dbg.FindMaxBenchmark::findMax_if@34 (line 18)
         │ │╭                 0x00007f34cc66e81f: jmp    0x00007f34cc66e839
         │ ││    ↗            0x00007f34cc66e821: mov    edx,ecx
  0.00%  │ ││    │            0x00007f34cc66e823: nop    DWORD PTR [rax+0x0]
         │ ││    │            0x00007f34cc66e82a: nop    WORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]
  0.89%  │ ││    │↗           0x00007f34cc66e830: add    r8d,0x4                        ;*iinc {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         │ ││    ││                                                                     ; - codes.dbg.FindMaxBenchmark::findMax_if@31 (line 18)
 12.36%  │ ││    ││           0x00007f34cc66e834: cmp    r8d,ebx
  0.11%  │ ││╭   ││           0x00007f34cc66e837: jge    0x00007f34cc66e871             ;*aload_3 {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         │ │││   ││                                                                     ; - codes.dbg.FindMaxBenchmark::findMax_if@18 (line 19)
  9.94%  │ │↘│   ││   ↗       0x00007f34cc66e839: mov    r11d,DWORD PTR [r9+r8*4+0x10]  ;*iaload {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         │ │ │   ││   │                                                                 ; - codes.dbg.FindMaxBenchmark::findMax_if@21 (line 19)
  0.11%  │ │ │   ││   │       0x00007f34cc66e83e: cmp    r11d,edx
 10.05%  │ │ │╭  ││   │       0x00007f34cc66e841: jg     0x00007f34cc66e862             ;*iinc {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         │ │ ││  ││   │                                                                 ; - codes.dbg.FindMaxBenchmark::findMax_if@31 (line 18)
  0.13%  │ │ ││  ││↗  │       0x00007f34cc66e843: mov    r11d,DWORD PTR [r9+r8*4+0x14]  ;*iaload {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         │ │ ││  │││  │                                                                 ; - codes.dbg.FindMaxBenchmark::findMax_if@21 (line 19)
  9.84%  │ │ ││  │││  │       0x00007f34cc66e848: cmp    r11d,edx
  0.11%  │ │ ││╭ │││  │       0x00007f34cc66e84b: jg     0x00007f34cc66e867             ;*iinc {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         │ │ │││ │││  │                                                                 ; - codes.dbg.FindMaxBenchmark::findMax_if@31 (line 18)
 10.02%  │ │ │││ │││↗ │       0x00007f34cc66e84d: mov    r11d,DWORD PTR [r9+r8*4+0x18]  ;*iaload {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         │ │ │││ ││││ │                                                                 ; - codes.dbg.FindMaxBenchmark::findMax_if@21 (line 19)
  0.33%  │ │ │││ ││││ │       0x00007f34cc66e852: cmp    r11d,edx
 23.63%  │ │ │││╭││││ │       0x00007f34cc66e855: jg     0x00007f34cc66e86c             ;*iinc {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         │ │ ││││││││ │                                                                 ; - codes.dbg.FindMaxBenchmark::findMax_if@31 (line 18)
  0.13%  │ │ ││││││││↗│       0x00007f34cc66e857: mov    ecx,DWORD PTR [r9+r8*4+0x1c]   ;*iaload {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         │ │ ││││││││││                                                                 ; - codes.dbg.FindMaxBenchmark::findMax_if@21 (line 19)
  9.89%  │ │ ││││││││││       0x00007f34cc66e85c: cmp    ecx,edx
  0.11%  │ │ ││││╰│││││       0x00007f34cc66e85e: jg     0x00007f34cc66e821             ;*if_icmple {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         │ │ ││││ │││││                                                                 ; - codes.dbg.FindMaxBenchmark::findMax_if@23 (line 19)
  9.71%  │ │ ││││ ╰││││       0x00007f34cc66e860: jmp    0x00007f34cc66e830
         │ │ │↘││  ││││       0x00007f34cc66e862: mov    edx,r11d
  0.00%  │ │ │ ││  ╰│││       0x00007f34cc66e865: jmp    0x00007f34cc66e843
         │ │ │ ↘│   │││       0x00007f34cc66e867: mov    edx,r11d
  0.00%  │ │ │  │   ╰││       0x00007f34cc66e86a: jmp    0x00007f34cc66e84d
         │ │ │  ↘    ││       0x00007f34cc66e86c: mov    edx,r11d
  0.00%  │ │ │       ╰│       0x00007f34cc66e86f: jmp    0x00007f34cc66e857
         │ │ ↘        │       0x00007f34cc66e871: mov    r11,QWORD PTR [r15+0x108]      ; ImmutableOopMap{r10=Oop r9=NarrowOop rdi=Oop }
         │ │          │                                                                 ;*goto {reexecute=1 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         │ │          │                                                                 ; - codes.dbg.FindMaxBenchmark::findMax_if@34 (line 18)
  0.00%  │ │          │       0x00007f34cc66e878: test   DWORD PTR [r11],eax            ;*goto {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         │ │          │                                                                 ; - codes.dbg.FindMaxBenchmark::findMax_if@34 (line 18)
         │ │          │                                                                 ;   {poll}
         │ │          │       0x00007f34cc66e87b: cmp    r8d,ebx
         │ │          ╰       0x00007f34cc66e87e: jl     0x00007f34cc66e839
         │ ↘                  0x00007f34cc66e880: cmp    r8d,ebp
  0.00%  │             ╭      0x00007f34cc66e883: jge    0x00007f34cc66e89a
         │             │      0x00007f34cc66e885: data16 xchg ax,ax                     ;*aload_3 {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         │             │                                                                ; - codes.dbg.FindMaxBenchmark::findMax_if@18 (line 19)
  0.00%  │             │ ↗    0x00007f34cc66e888: mov    r11d,DWORD PTR [r9+r8*4+0x10]  ;*iaload {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         │             │ │                                                              ; - codes.dbg.FindMaxBenchmark::findMax_if@21 (line 19)
  0.01%  │             │ │    0x00007f34cc66e88d: cmp    r11d,edx
         │             │╭│    0x00007f34cc66e890: jg     0x00007f34cc66e8b8
         │             │││↗   0x00007f34cc66e892: inc    r8d                            ;*iinc {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         │             ││││                                                             ; - codes.dbg.FindMaxBenchmark::findMax_if@31 (line 18)
         │             ││││   0x00007f34cc66e895: cmp    r8d,ebp
         │             ││╰│   0x00007f34cc66e898: jl     0x00007f34cc66e888             ;*if_icmpge {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         │             ││ │                                                             ; - codes.dbg.FindMaxBenchmark::findMax_if@15 (line 18)
         │             ↘│ │↗  0x00007f34cc66e89a: test   r10,r10
  0.00%  │              │ ││  0x00007f34cc66e89d: je     0x00007f34cc66e8da
         │              │ ││  0x00007f34cc66e89f: mov    rsi,r10
         │              │ ││  0x00007f34cc66e8a2: nop
         │              │ ││  0x00007f34cc66e8a3: call   0x00007f34cc66e920             ; ImmutableOopMap{}
         │              │ ││                                                            ;*invokevirtual consume {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         │              │ ││                                                            ; - codes.dbg.FindMaxBenchmark::findMax_if@39 (line 24)
         │              │ ││                                                            ;   {optimized virtual_call}
  0.00%  │              │ ││  0x00007f34cc66e8a8: add    rsp,0x20
  0.01%  │              │ ││  0x00007f34cc66e8ac: pop    rbp
         │              │ ││  0x00007f34cc66e8ad: mov    r10,QWORD PTR [r15+0x108]
         │              │ ││  0x00007f34cc66e8b4: test   DWORD PTR [r10],eax            ;   {poll_return}
         │              │ ││  0x00007f34cc66e8b7: ret
         │              ↘ ││  0x00007f34cc66e8b8: mov    edx,r11d
         │                ╰│  0x00007f34cc66e8bb: jmp    0x00007f34cc66e892
         │                 │  0x00007f34cc66e8bd: mov    edx,0x80000000
         │                 ╰  0x00007f34cc66e8c2: jmp    0x00007f34cc66e89a
         ↘                    0x00007f34cc66e8c4: mov    esi,0xffffff7e
                              0x00007f34cc66e8c9: mov    QWORD PTR [rsp],r10
                              0x00007f34cc66e8cd: mov    DWORD PTR [rsp+0x8],r9d
....................................................................................................
```

**Observations:**

- there is only one significant difference between `findMax_if` and `findMax_if_else`:

`0x00007f34cc66e85e: jg 0x00007f34cc66e821` vs `0x00007fc7a8671ade: jle 0x00007fc7a8671ab0`

- `findMax_intrinsicMax` which laverage intrinsic `Math.max` has worst performance, which is counterintuitive to me.

**Questions:**

- Is normal to add `else` statement containing code which doesn't change anything (like `x = x;`)? Especially in code which is executed on one thread.
- Where is the real source of thourghput difference? I see the `jg` (jump if greater) is not the `jle` (jump if less or equal). Effectively the first condition is the inverted second condition.
- What is the point of using `Math.max` if simple `if else` statement has higher throughput?

[Source code on GitHub](https://github.com/JakubBialy/javaifternarybenchmark)

`run_tests.sh` runs benchmark and generate plot.

Comment: If I read the graph correctly, we're talking about a difference of roughly 15% between fastest and slowest version. To me, that's pretty close. If in any real-world application, maxing an array takes a significant amount of run time, I'd think about a change of algorithm (avoiding that maxing process), with the potential of a much higher performance gain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, in order to minimize the amount of irrelevant ASM code and to simplify analysis, let's add the following JVM options:

- `-XX:LoopUnrollLimit=0` - turns off loop unrolling;
- `-XX:-UseCountedLoopSafepoints` - eliminates safepoint polling from the loop.

Now the performance difference in favor of `if_else` will be even bigger, while the result assembly will be much simpler. Here is the loop body of both benchmarks.

**findMax_if**

```
         ╭     0x0000029707af78f5: jmp     29707af7908h
         │ ↗   0x0000029707af78f7: mov     r8d,ecx
         │ │   0x0000029707af78fa: nop     word ptr [rax+rax+0h]
  0,66%  │ │↗  0x0000029707af7900: inc     r9d               ;*iinc {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         │ ││                                                ; - codes.dbg.FindMaxBenchmark::findMax_if@31 (line 18)
  1,02%  │ ││  0x0000029707af7903: cmp     r9d,r10d
         │╭││  0x0000029707af7906: jnl     29707af7914h      ;*aload_3 {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         ││││                                                ; - codes.dbg.FindMaxBenchmark::findMax_if@18 (line 19)
  2,06%  ↘│││  0x0000029707af7908: mov     ecx,dword ptr [r11+r9*4+10h]
          │││                                                ;*iaload {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
          │││                                                ; - codes.dbg.FindMaxBenchmark::findMax_if@21 (line 19)
 50,86%   │││  0x0000029707af790d: cmp     ecx,r8d
  0,02%   │╰│  0x0000029707af7910: jnle    29707af78f7h      ;*if_icmple {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
          │ │                                                ; - codes.dbg.FindMaxBenchmark::findMax_if@23 (line 19)
 41,01%   │ ╰  0x0000029707af7912: jmp     29707af7900h      ;*if_icmpge {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
          │                                                  ; - codes.dbg.FindMaxBenchmark::findMax_if@15 (line 18)
          ↘    0x0000029707af7914: test    rbx,rbx
```

**findMax_if_else**

```
         ╭     0x00000137d24d4b75: jmp     137d24d4b88h
         │  ↗  0x00000137d24d4b77: mov     r8d,ecx
         │  │  0x00000137d24d4b7a: nop     word ptr [rax+rax+0h]
 72,63%  │ ↗│  0x00000137d24d4b80: inc     r9d               ;*iinc {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         │ ││                                                ; - codes.dbg.FindMaxBenchmark::findMax_if_else@36 (line 33)
  0,05%  │ ││  0x00000137d24d4b83: cmp     r9d,r10d
  0,01%  │╭││  0x00000137d24d4b86: jnl     137d24d4b94h      ;*aload_3 {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         ││││                                                ; - codes.dbg.FindMaxBenchmark::findMax_if_else@18 (line 34)
  6,47%  ↘│││  0x00000137d24d4b88: mov     ecx,dword ptr [r11+r9*4+10h]
          │││                                                ;*iaload {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
          │││                                                ; - codes.dbg.FindMaxBenchmark::findMax_if_else@21 (line 34)
 15,93%   │││  0x00000137d24d4b8d: cmp     ecx,r8d
  0,18%   │╰│  0x00000137d24d4b90: jle     137d24d4b80h      ;*if_icmple {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
          │ │                                                ; - codes.dbg.FindMaxBenchmark::findMax_if_else@23 (line 34)
  0,01%   │ ╰  0x00000137d24d4b92: jmp     137d24d4b77h      ;*if_icmpge {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
          │                                                  ; - codes.dbg.FindMaxBenchmark::findMax_if_else@15 (line 33)
          ↘    0x00000137d24d4b94: test    rbx,rbx
```

This aligns with your findings: the only difference between two compilations is the inverted jump condition: `jnle` vs. `jle`. Why `jnle` variant is slower then?

If we carefully look at the benchmark code, we'll realize that the point where the current maximum changes, happens quite seldom. On average, `data[i] > result` is true only 14 times per the entire loop. This means, `jnle` branch is taken only 0.001% time, and the rest 99.999% time the execution goes through the next `jmp` instruction.

On the contrary, `jle` instruction in the second variant is taken 99.999% time, and the execution almost never reaches the following `jmp`. So, the first loop retires 7 instructions per iteration, while the second one - only 6 instructions.

JMH has built-in `perfnorm` profiler (available on Linux) that supplements benchmark results with CPU performance counters stats. Let's run it with `-prof perfnorm`.

```
Benchmark                                                Mode  Cnt        Score    Error  Units
FindMaxBenchmark.findMax_if                             thrpt   10     1447.576 ±  8.854  ops/s
FindMaxBenchmark.findMax_if:CPI                         thrpt             0.335            #/op
FindMaxBenchmark.findMax_if:L1-dcache-load-misses       thrpt         63971.361            #/op
FindMaxBenchmark.findMax_if:L1-dcache-loads             thrpt       1014974.522            #/op
FindMaxBenchmark.findMax_if:L1-dcache-stores            thrpt          6105.121            #/op
FindMaxBenchmark.findMax_if:L1-icache-load-misses       thrpt          1641.074            #/op
FindMaxBenchmark.findMax_if:branch-misses               thrpt           146.305            #/op
FindMaxBenchmark.findMax_if:branches                    thrpt       3006620.048            #/op
FindMaxBenchmark.findMax_if:cycles                      thrpt       2358093.526            #/op
FindMaxBenchmark.findMax_if:dTLB-load-misses            thrpt          1085.740            #/op
FindMaxBenchmark.findMax_if:dTLB-loads                  thrpt       1012739.362            #/op
FindMaxBenchmark.findMax_if:dTLB-store-misses           thrpt            21.985            #/op
FindMaxBenchmark.findMax_if:dTLB-stores                 thrpt          6146.243            #/op
FindMaxBenchmark.findMax_if:iTLB-load-misses            thrpt           139.741            #/op
FindMaxBenchmark.findMax_if:iTLB-loads                  thrpt            42.031            #/op
FindMaxBenchmark.findMax_if:instructions                thrpt       7039394.622            #/op
FindMaxBenchmark.findMax_if_else                        thrpt   10     2472.400 ± 36.958  ops/s
FindMaxBenchmark.findMax_if_else:CPI                    thrpt             0.229            #/op
FindMaxBenchmark.findMax_if_else:L1-dcache-load-misses  thrpt         63353.481            #/op
FindMaxBenchmark.findMax_if_else:L1-dcache-loads        thrpt       1007856.753            #/op
FindMaxBenchmark.findMax_if_else:L1-dcache-stores       thrpt          3696.805            #/op
FindMaxBenchmark.findMax_if_else:L1-icache-load-misses  thrpt          1182.253            #/op
FindMaxBenchmark.findMax_if_else:branch-misses          thrpt            72.334            #/op
FindMaxBenchmark.findMax_if_else:branches               thrpt       2000460.845            #/op
FindMaxBenchmark.findMax_if_else:cycles                 thrpt       1380927.546            #/op
FindMaxBenchmark.findMax_if_else:dTLB-load-misses       thrpt           845.629            #/op
FindMaxBenchmark.findMax_if_else:dTLB-loads             thrpt       1006135.685            #/op
FindMaxBenchmark.findMax_if_else:dTLB-store-misses      thrpt            13.336            #/op
FindMaxBenchmark.findMax_if_else:dTLB-stores            thrpt          3545.950            #/op
FindMaxBenchmark.findMax_if_else:iTLB-load-misses       thrpt            80.233            #/op
FindMaxBenchmark.findMax_if_else:iTLB-loads             thrpt            19.009            #/op
FindMaxBenchmark.findMax_if_else:instructions           thrpt       6018937.376            #/op
```

Perf counters confirm that `findMax_if` executes 7M instructions with 3M branches, whereas `findMax_if_else` executes 6M instructions with 2M branches. I guess it's clear now where the difference comes from, so what about the other questions?

> Is normal to add else statement containing code which doesn't change
> anything

I don't think so. At least because this looks counterintuitive, and makes the code harder to read and to understand. It's just a matter of luck that the redundant code inverted the branch condition in a good way. Replace your random array with a sorted one, so that `data[i] > result` will be mostly true, and then `findMax_if` will become the fastest option.

> What is the point of using Math.max if simple if else statement has
> higher throughput?

Again, this is not always true. This highly depends on the nature of the data. When the branches are easy to predict, `if` statement performs better. But as soon as the branch predictor starts to fail often, the performance will drop drastically. `Math.max`, being a JVM intrinsic method, is translated to the branchless `cmov` instruction, which has an advantage of the stable performance regardless of the data distribution.

Here is an example data set where `Math.max` greatly outperforms all other options:

```
public void setup() {
    Random r = new Random();
    this.tab = r.ints(SIZE).sorted().toArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i += ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(3)) {
        tab[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent explanation (as always). Is there anything, that a programmer can do at a Java code level, in situation which the `if` condition is extremely rarely true, to encourage compiler to avoid unnecesary instructioin execution? Secondly, i am a little suprised, that the C2 compiler didn't optimised `findMax_if` condition based on runtime statistics.

Comment: @JakubBiały I'm afraid there is no a reliable way to force JIT prefer one branch over another. In fact, C2 *does* use statistics to layout basic blocks, but in this case it somehow works wrong (haven't figured out why yet). It's interesting that when this optimization is turned off (`-XX:-BlockLayoutByFrequency`), both `findMax_if` and `findMax_if_else` are compiled in an equally fast way.